# Downloading a .JSON file in WP8.1

Tags: c#, json, download, windows-phone-8.1, httpwebrequest

For the moment, I have this code:

```
string uri = "http://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=20&page=1";
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
   if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
   {
      var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("/list_movies.json");
      var articles = root.data.movies.Select(m => new Article { Name = m.title, ImagePath = m.medium_cover_image, Year = m.year.ToString() }).ToList();        
   }
   else
   {
       var dialog = new MessageDialog("Their seems to be a problem retrieving the data...");
       dialog.Title = "Sorry";
   }
```

But Visual Studio is telling me that GetResponse (2nd line) doesn't exist. What is the problem? :/

Comment: When you say "doesn't exist" do you mean that the method is missing or that it returns null?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't precise. VS just says it is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at HttpClient. This works perfectly on WP8.1.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancel))
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<T>(new JsonTextReader(reader));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  i've tried to get this to work, but I am now greeted with this error when I try and execute my app: http://pastebin.com/w6uNEe4B. Here is my current code: http://pastebin.com/vbiEbUZG . Is it an error with the way I have retrieved the data, or something else?

Comment: StreamReader.ToString() does not do what you are expecting. It returns the name of the class (System.IO.StreamReader). Try .ReadToEnd().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries" Nuget package version of the assemblies doesn't support that method. Instead you're limited to the following, which basically means you'll have to use BeginGetRequestStream and the other async methods:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.95).aspx

Here's an example of how to make the request (the context is a Silverlight article, but it applies to your situation):
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/implementing-the-http-requestresponse-model-inside-of-silverlight/